# how to set static ip address for Gigabyte running ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, airport-extreme

This is my office network setup

[image: /Users/kim/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-12-18 at 11.34.15 AM.png]

**Please also note that the AirportExtreme itself is connected to a D-link router which I have no access to its web console.**

My [Gigabyte 6200](http://www.gigabyte.sg/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5690#ov) is connected to the Airport Extreme using a lan cable.

The Gigabyte Brix is running 14.04 Ubuntu Server (not the desktop with the nice GUI)

When I set the `/etc/network/interfaces` to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and then `sudo ifdown -v eth0` and `sudo ifup -v eth0`, I can do `ping www.google.com` successfully

And then `ifconfig` gives me:

```
eth0   inetaddr: 192.168.1.39 Bcast: 192.168.1.155 Mask:255.255.255.0
```

When I set the `/etc/network/interfaces` to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.39
     netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And then `ifconfig` gives me:

```
eth0   inetaddr: 192.168.1.39 Bcast: 192.168.1.155 Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**BUT**

and then `sudo ifdown -v eth0` and `sudo ifup -v eth0`, I do `ping www.google.com`  and get **a unknown host error**

I have also tried other IP addresses.

How do I set a static IP address based on my situation?

Comment: You are going to need to set one or more DNS servers when you statically configure your address. DHCP handles that for you.

Comment: thanks! your comment helped. I also needed to add gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just add gateway and dns to the config and it will work.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.39
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.1.1
     dns-nameservers 208.91.112.53 208.91.112.52
```